# How do I query only for the dependencies declared under deps in the BUILD file?

Tags: bazel, bazel-java, bazel-query

How do I query only for the dependencies declared under `deps`?

For example, given the given target

```
java_library(
    name = "my-library",
    srcs = glob(["src/main/java/**/*.java"]),
    deps = [
        ":some-target",
        "//some-package:another-target",
        artifact("some-maven:some-artifact"),
        artifact("another-maven:another-artifact"),
    ],
)
```

How do I query just the dependencies directly defined in `deps`? That is,

```
":some-target",
"//some-package:another-target",
artifact("some-maven:some-artifact"),
artifact("another-maven:another-artifact"),
```

`bazel query deps(my-library)` returns me many other dependencies I am not interested in (e.g. source files, platform targets, other internal targets, etc.).

Comment: `bazel query 'deps(//my:target)' --nohost_deps --noimplicit_deps` should improve the result a bit - you can also try `buildozer "print deps" "//some:target"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download buildozer from [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/buildtools/releases). Add buildozer to your environment path.

```
buildozer "print deps" "//some:target"
```

This will list what can be found in the `deps` attribute, e.g.:

```
[
    ":main_qrc",
    ":main_window",
    ":resource2",
    "//okapi:print_version",
    "@rules_qt//:qt_core",
    "@rules_qt//:qt_qml",
    "@rules_qt//:qt_widgets",
    "//okapi:command_line_arguments",
] + select({
    ":windows_x86_64": [":win_resources"],
    "//conditions:default": [],
})
```

Builddozer just gives you a text copy of what can be found in the `deps` attribute. There will be no transitive dependencies and things like selectes will not be resolved.

In contrast using Bazel's `cquery` you can get all dependencies including transitive ones without source files this way:

```
bazel cquery --config=your_config 'deps(//some:target) except kind("source file", deps(//some:target))'
```